# Save OffsetDateTime to Room database

Tags: android, android-room, offsetdatetime

I have a data class with a field of type [`OffsetDateTime`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/OffsetDateTime). With the room database, I have the following error:

> ```
> Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor.
>     private final java.time.OffsetDateTime
> ```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To persist Date Object in Roomdb, you need to use Type Converters

> Suppose you need to persist instances of Date in your Room database.
> Room doesn't know how to persist Date objects, so you need to define
> type converters:

```
class Converters {
  @TypeConverter
  fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Date? {
    return value?.let { Date(it) }
  }

  @TypeConverter
  fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?): Long? {
    return date?.time?.toLong()
  }
}
```

Example given here will give you a better idea:
[Referencing complex data using Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data)